# What are the effects of aging?

Tags: dnd-5e, aging

I am new to D&D.

I did not find any official ruling concerning the effects of aging in the PHB. I know that in some systems aging can have adverse and/or beneficial effects on stats.

I ask because I am currently playing Monk and at 15th he will receive **Timeless Body** which prevents "**the frailty of old age**". What is the mechanic, if any, that this applies to?

Answer (score 22):

There are *no* current, directly codified, effects of old age.

However. There are several spells and other effects that *do* cause you to age prematurely. The Monk would be immune to these. There are also *basic* guidelines on how the races age and when they become adults/typically die.

For an example of a monster capable of aging a creature, we have the Ghost who can cause aging of 1d4 × 10 years with one of their features. While there are *no direct* effects, the DM can very well rule that this kind of effect would cause you to no longer be an effective adventurer.

As [GMNoob points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/47480/1084), we may find out the mechanical effects of aging in the DMG, but largely, these will be left to the DM's discretion.

Comment: They are likely to be somewhat similar to D&D 3.5e's ageing table: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#age

Comment: That aging table has always irked me. Increase in mental abilities as one ages already has a mechanic: XP. Really, life is pain; _all_ ability scores should decline with age. Samsara-based house rule: for every year over a certain threshold for each race, choose an ability score at random and make a save; on failure, -1 from that ability. At a further threshold, do this for _every_ ability (and possibly ramp up frequency of checks).  When Con reaches zero, you're dead. More realistic... but probably not more _fun_.

Comment: In case you decide to update this answer: While the DMG does include some mechanics relating to aging (an epic boon that stops it, a potion that reduces one's age, some planes where you don't age), there are no mechanics about the effect of aging on ability scores and such.

Answer (score 15):

### There are none.

Neither the *Player's Handbook* nor the *Dungeon Master's Guide* list any mechanical effects of age. They only refer in passing to dying of old age, and the frailty of old age. The spells *resurrection*, *revivify*, and *true resurrection* (*Player's Handbook* pp272, 284) all state that a creature that's died of old age is not an eligible target.

---

*Interestingly, neither* raise dead *(270) nor* reincarnate *(271) list any such restriction. So by using either one, a character might live forever, barring [Inevitables](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#marut-inevitable) (I know that's 3.5 material...).*

---

#### There can be...

The designers neglected to include mechanical effects for aging, leaving the issue up to each table to decide. Whether intentional or not, this leaves much leeway for DMs and players to decide how they want to portray aging, or even whether they want to bother.

By default, age is nothing but a cosmetic or story effect.

Answer (score 5):

Without the DMG, there are no current mechanical effects of old age, other than those that your table decides.