# Is a Stone Giant immune from Petrification?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, conditions, immunities

Can a Medusa's Gaze attack, say, petrify a Stone Giant?

For example a Fire Giant is immune from Fire, the same for Frost giants for cold etc. It seams to follow that a stone giant should have immunity from Petrification.

As a more general question what about all other 'earth' subtype creature, are they immune, the MM seams to ignore this. Where as most fire creature (etc) are immune from Fire effects (etc).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with 3.5e to answer properly, but from a thematic standpoint : if you're made out of stone, it doesn't mean you cannot be turned into stone by a magical effect. It could always be a different kind of stone, which still means you'd be stopped from doing anything, like petrification is meant to do.

Comment: Related : [What type of stone do targets of Flesh to Stone, and Petrification, turn into?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133490/77044)

Comment: reminds me of how in Nethack, petrifying a golem turns it into a stone golem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creatures of the [Earth substype](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#earthSubtype), like Stone Giants, does not gain immunity to petrification or any other effect from their Earth substype.

Unlike the [Cold substype](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#coldSubtype), there is no call out for immunity of any kind in the [Earth substype](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#earthSubtype).

You can see the most common subtypes at d20srd here: https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm